# How HD video works on modern hardware(OpenGL)?

Tags: opengl, gpu

Back in the days of DOS, the way we showed graphics in computers was just copying raw image data into memory for every frame.

Because of the bandwidth between the CPU and the GPU, this proves to be very ineffective. In order to send every frame to the screen in modern resolutions, we need something like

1080 * 1200 * 4(color data) * 60(frames per second) = 311 megabytes every second.

So we preloaded the textures and vertices into the GPU memory and we just send the transformations.

So, how HD video playing is solved in modern hardware? Is there a way to compress every frame that is sent to the GPU? Or we just send the raw 311MB/s like in the old days?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming decompression is not being done at least in part on the GPU itself, then yes, you send video by uploading the image each frame to graphics memory.

Your math is off though. 1080p is 1920x1080. 30fps video at 1080p requires ~238MB/sec. And... that's perfectly doable. Even [PCIe 1.0 x1 could handle that (though barely)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express), and GPUs tend to use x16 slots, so 16x more bandwidth. And PCIe is at version 4.0 (on most machines), so it's much faster today.